# Uncaught TypeError: Argument of the type array, null given

Tags: php, arrays, product, data-migration, magento-2.3

What is the mean Argument of the type array, null given,

Error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 3 passed to
> Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory::mergeMetadataElement()
> must be of the type array, null given, called in
> /var/www/html/giriusa/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Element/UiComponentFactory.php
> on line 384 and defined in
> /var/www/html/giriusa/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Element/UiComponentFactory.php:337
> Stack trace: #0
> /var/www/html/giriusa/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Element/UiComponentFactory.php(384):
> Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory->mergeMetadataElement(Array,
> 'configurableExi...', NULL, false) #1
> /var/www/html/giriusa/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Element/UiComponentFactory.php(412):
> Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory->mergeMetadataItem(Array,
> Array, false) #2
> /var/www/html/giriusa/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Element/UiComponentFactory.php(412):
> Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory->mergeMetadataItem(Array,
> Array, false) #3 /var/www/html/giriusa/lib/internal/Magento/Fram in
> /var/www/html/giriusa/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Element/UiComponentFactory.php
> on line 337

Path : lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Element/UiComponentFactory.php

> UiComponentFactory::mergeMetadataElement() must be of the type array,
> null given

```
protected function mergeMetadataElement(array $bundleComponents, $name, array $data, $reverseMerge = false)
{
    if (isset($bundleComponents[$name])) {
        $bundleComponents[$name] = $reverseMerge
            ? array_replace_recursive($data, $bundleComponents[$name])
            : array_replace_recursive($bundleComponents[$name], $data);
        return [$bundleComponents, true];
    } else {
        foreach ($bundleComponents as &$childData) {
            if (isset($childData['attributes']['class'])
                && is_a($childData['attributes']['class'], \Magento\Ui\Component\Container::class, true)
                && isset($childData['children']) && is_array($childData['children'])
            ) {
                list($childData['children'], $isMerged) = $this->mergeMetadataElement(
                    $childData['children'],
                    $name,
                    $data,
                    $reverseMerge
                );
                if ($isMerged) {
                    return [$bundleComponents, true];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return [$bundleComponents, false];
}
```

Note: After migration from 1.9 getting above error before its working good.

Comment: It means you're passing a `null` value to the third parameter of the function (`$data`).

Comment: This is the Magento core file, before migration, there is no error after migration from 1.9.2.3 i have faced an error during add new product.